# 0 is treated as "none" decimalfield django

Tags: django

I have the following model field:

```
expenses = models.DecimalField(null=True, blank=True, max_digits=11, decimal_places=2, validators=[MinValueValidator(0)])
```

My problem:

If the user sets 0, Django treats as "None" when it should be 0. It should only appear as "None" in case no value was attributed to it. Is there any easy work around for this?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the above comment it seems the problem is that you're using the template tag `default` which will evaluate `0` as a falsy value and display your default value.

What you want is `default_if_none` (which will only match `None` and not 0): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#default-if-none

Answer (score 0):

Set the value in `MinValueValidtor` using `Decimal`:

```
expenses = models.DecimalField(null=True, blank=True, max_digits=11, decimal_places=2, 
                               validators=[MinValueValidator(Decimal('0.00'))])
```

Comment: I believe this has to do on how Django interprets the value in the database. It seems `0` is interpreted as `None`. I did what you mentioned and didn't work.

Comment: Do you mean in database it is saved as `None` or you get some error in the form?

Comment: In the database it is recorded as ´0´, or ´0.00´, however when I try to display the value in the template it appears as "None".

Comment: Could you add code in your question used in the template?

Comment: Expenses: `{{ advertisement.get_expenses|default:"Not informed"|intcomma }}`